# How to set return url in php

Tags: php

I have 3 different sites like A.com, B.com, C.com..and want to set connectivity between these 3. like:

```
A -> B   (->request),
B -> C,
C => B   (=> response),
B => A,
```

and in this whole process B.com is not at all visible to user, my problem is exists with B=>A(B response to A), the response i am getting from C.com is inserting in DB at B.com and now have to send that response to A.com.

I am using curl for these purpose, but it's not redirecting me on A.com, it's showing response at B.com itself.

```
 $url ="http://A.com"
      $fields= array("name" =>"myname",
                    "place" => "India");

       $ch = curl_init();
       $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $fields,
      );
      curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
      $url = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
```

code is in B.com/response.php file
the above code is showing response on B.com and i want that response on A.com.

Comment: Such cross domain posts are very uncommon and cause lots of issues. Take good care for your access control headers, otherwise the https security measurements of modern browsers will frustrate most of your users with that setup... Question: is there a reason for this very exotic setup? Why don't you simply proxy the requests using a single front end server?

Comment: Thanks for reply.i had tried it with header content "array("Content-Type:multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8;")" also, but no luck. not sue if can use any other way also for this.

Comment: With "access control headers" I referred to the cross origin access control header. Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS